# how to chage the default currency while (Ether to any other currency) while when signTransaction in flutter

Tags: flutter, transactions, ethereum, cryptocurrency

I want to change the currency while signing a transaction, so the user has to send that particular cryptocurrency. By default, when I am sending request it is sent to metamask with ETH token, I want to change it, so it shows other currency (any other currency like bitcoin etc.) when trying to pay

```
 await client.sendTransaction(
  credentials,
  Transaction(
    to: EthereumAddress.fromHex('0xC91...3706'),
    gasPrice: EtherAmount.inWei(BigInt.one),
    maxGas: 100000,
    value: EtherAmount.fromUnitAndValue(EtherUnit.ether, 1),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function that you mentioned is from package:web3dart which is used only for Ethereum ( or Ethereum like ) blockchain. For other blockchains, you must use other specific packages. For example, for bitcoin you can use [bitcoin_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/bitcoin_flutter) package, or for Solana you can use [solana_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/solana_dart) package.